# consuming external web services(https) in share point hosted apps resulting cross-domain issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, ajax

We are not able to consume external web services deployed in a separate domain  from sharepoint hosted apps,using jquery ajax.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating Apps for SharePoint you need to define an authorized remote endpoint in your AppManifest and then use the Web Proxy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Example using the JS Object Model

Define `http://services.odata.org/` as a remote endpoint in the AppManifest file of your App for SP project (or on the configuration page if you're using Napa). Then make a call like this (a simplification from the above link):

```
(function() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo();
    request.set_url(
        "http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories"
        );
    request.set_method("GET");

    request.set_headers({ "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" });
    var response = SP.WebProxy.invoke(context, request);

    context.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler);

    function successHandler() {
        if (response.get_statusCode() == 200) {
            // Load the OData source from the response.
            var responseData = JSON.parse(response.get_body());
            // log this to console so you can inspect it
            console.log(responseData)
        }
        else {
            var errordesc = "Status code: " + response.get_statusCode();
            errordesc += "\n" + response.get_body();
            console.log(errordesc)
        }
    }
    function errorHandler() {
        console.log(response.get_body());
    }
})();
```

You can also find a REST example on the MSDN site at the link above

To use this in your environment you would define the domain where your webservices are (instead of services.odata.org) as the authorized endpoint, then make your request against that location.

Something that you may run in to if your web services use ports other than 80 and 443: Your App Server needs to have port access to the ports where your webservices are hosted. So you may need to configure your firewall to allow those ports to the server hosting your app domains. For SharePoint online, you are only allowed to request remote endpoint data on ports 80 and 443.

Comment: its working in SharePoint hosted app also